# How can I get minimised windows in different desktops to un-minimise in my current desktop?

Tags: windows, window-manager

If I minimise a window in Desktop 1, then move to Desktop 2 and un-minimise the window it moves me back to Desktop 1. Is it possible to make it un-minimise and stay in Desktop 2 instead?

Comment: No. Windows stay in their Desktop. TBH, I've always found that minimizing windows makes things more disorganized, and I forget what's going on. There are so many other ways of selecting relevant windows without hiding them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's technically possible, but with a side-effect you may not like. Set the App's Space affinity to "All Desktops", then it will always follow you.

[image]